# Какой тип надо указать, чтобы функция работала?

Tags: java, шаблоны

Какой тип надо указать, чтобы функция работала?

```
foo(... x){
   return x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Укажите тип `int`

```
int foo(int x){ return x + 1; }
```

Comment: мне шаблонный тип нужен

Comment: типа Comparable только для сложения

Comment: java.lang.Object

Comment: @Xoxole спасибо